# CyberPanel SSL auto-renew

Tags: ssl, cron, cyber-panel

So, I have OpenLightSpeed server with CyberPanel installed. My issue is that once I issue the SSL with a standard CyberPanel tool, it works for 90 days only, regular Lets Encrypt cert.
There is a CRON job add possibility in the CP, but I`m not sure it will work properly to auto-renew. Esspecialy the restart part. Here it is:

```
/root/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue -d yourdomainname.com -d www.yourdomainname.com --cert-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomainname.com/cert.pem --key-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomainname.com/privkey.pem --fullchain-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomainname.com/fullchain.pem -w /home/yourdomainname.com/public_html –-force && systemctl restart lsws
```

Could someone advise, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The SSL renewal is auto in CyberPanel. Like after 90 days this cron will automatically run to issue SSL in cyberpanel you can see the command in the CyberPanel main log but if due to some issue like forceful redirection or anything SSL not successfully issued you have to issue manually then.